# How to expect string to start with specified variable

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a simple function constructing a string from a complex object. For the sake of simplicity I will go for this

```
public generateMessage(property: string): string {
    return `${property} more text.`;
}
```

My test currently is

```
    it('starts the message with the property name', () => {
        const property = 'field';
        const message: string = myClass.generateMessage(property);

        expect(message).toEqual(`${property} more text.`);
    });
```

The only thing relevant here is that the generated message starts with the property. Is there a way I can check if a string starts with that property? Pseudo code:

`expect(message).toStartWith(property);`

or do I have to do it on my own using the `startsWith()` method for strings? The best solution coming to my mind currently is

```
expect(message.startsWith(property)).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [.toMatch(regexpOrString)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchregexporstring) and regexp to do this. The regexp pattern equivalent to [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is `/^field?/`

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
class MyClass {
  public generateMessage(property: string): string {
    return `${property} more text.`;
  }
}

export { MyClass };
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './';

describe('61290819', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    const property = 'field';
    const message: string = myClass.generateMessage(property);
    expect(message).toMatch(new RegExp(`^${property}?`));
  });

  it('should pass too', () => {
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    const property = 'f_ield'; // make some changes
    const message: string = myClass.generateMessage(property);
    expect(message).not.toMatch(new RegExp('^field?'));
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61290819/index.test.ts (9.814s)
  61290819
    ✓ should pass (5ms)
    ✓ should not pass

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.417s
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `expect(message.startsWith(property)).toBe(true)`? Because I find that more readable.

Comment: nothing wrong, just the error message will be "expected +True got -False" which does not give any hint about the actually value of the message. (to be fair, i'm not sure what the toMatch error message looks like)

Comment: What's up with the `?` in the regex? Why is it okay if the string starts with "field" OR with "fiel"?

Comment: Note that you could use a regex literal here too instead of dynamically creating a regexp object: `.toMatch(/^field/)`

Answer (score 9):

[@slideshowp2 s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61314342/1761588) is correct, but the `?` is not needed as it only means *zero or 1 time*

so the following is sufficent

```js
expect("this is a test").toMatch(/^this/);
```

Answer (score 1):

As [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `0` only if a substring is in the start, we could use it for the subject task.
Example of a test case that passes:

```
it('Should start with...', () => {
    expect('foobar'.indexOf('foo')).toBe(0); // 0
    expect('foobar'.indexOf('bar')).not.toBe(0); // not 0 (3)
    expect('foobar'.indexOf('aaa')).not.toBe(0); // not 0 (-1)
});
```